# FIR filter output result Interpretation While input is taken from ADC161S626: 16 bit

Tags: filter, filtering, adc, digital-filter

I have implemented a 20 order FIR Low pass filter, 1000 HZ cutoff frequency on Sparten - 6 FPGA. First I calculate the coefficients in Matlab, Then I directly put them in vhdl code. Here are my coefficients.

```
    H(0) <= to_signed(26,16); --10000HZ cutoff
    H(1) <= to_signed(67,16);
    H(2) <= to_signed(169,16);
    H(3) <= to_signed(369,16);
    H(4) <= to_signed(686,16);
    H(5) <= to_signed(1111,16);
    H(6) <= to_signed(1606,16);
    H(7) <= to_signed(2108,16);
    H(8) <= to_signed(2542,16);
    H(9) <= to_signed(2836,16);
    H(10) <= to_signed(2940,16);
    H(11) <= to_signed(2836,16);
    H(12) <= to_signed(2542,16);
    H(13) <= to_signed(2108,16);
    H(14) <= to_signed(1606,16);
    H(15) <= to_signed(1111,16);
    H(16) <= to_signed(686,16);
    H(17) <= to_signed(369,16);
    H(18) <= to_signed(169,16);
    H(19) <= to_signed(67,16);
    H(20) <= to_signed(26,16);
```

Now Actually I am taking an torque feedback Input from some sensor, The torque is converted in voltage. The voltage is digitize into 16 bit format.The filtered value, output of the filter is in 32 bit format.

Here is the snapshot of Teraterm.
How do I convert the these values to voltages ?
[image]

Thanks.